# How to specify python version to use when leveraging pip

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to run pip to install some libraries for python 2.7, but in my windows shell, its identifying it with python 3.X that I have installed and installing the packages to the python libs folder, or some folder relative to python 3.x. How can I specify pip to install specified package to only 2.7 in the CLI instead of python 3, and vice-versa?

Perhaps I should try to use virtual environment with python 3 running and run pip from there?

> `pip install pyvisa`

I expect this to be an issue because I have no unique environment variable to specify which version of python I want pip to use.

Answer (score 0):

Try `py -2 -m pip install pyvisa` for Python 2 and `py -3 -m pip install pyvisa` for Python 3. The `py` launcher that allows you to run stuff both in Python 2 and in Python 3 comes bundled with recent versions of both Python 2 and Python 3 for Windows, but it's optional. If you chose not to install `py`, you can instead use `C:\Python2\python.exe -m pip install pyvisa`, as an example -- substitute your own Python 2 path there.